# DateTimeEdit, TimeEdit stepBy

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimeedit

I looked for solutions, but I did not find them.
I wanted to make it into a QTimeEdit by pressing the up or down arrow on the minutes, and only those, step 10. I wanted to write in the stylesheet.
I've tried these solutions, but they do not work.

```
QTimeEdit::MinuteSection{
stepBy:10;
}

QTimeEdit QAbstractSpinBox{
stepEnabled: True;
}

QTimeEdit QAbstractSpinBox::MinuteSection {
stepEnabled: True;
stepBy:10;
}
```

In all cases above the minutes always advance one and not 10.
However, the code does not give me any errors.
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

```
class timeEdit(QtWidgets.QTimeEdit):
    def stepBy(self, steps):
        if self.currentSection() == self.MinuteSection:
            steps=10


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):#FFFFFF
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(800, 480)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.timeEdit = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self)
        self.timeEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 30, 200, 100))
        self.timeEdit.stepBy(1)
        self.timeEdit2 = QtWidgets.QTimeEdit(self)
        self.timeEdit2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 230, 200, 100))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app =QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    Window= MainWindow()
    Window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Qt Style Sheets only serve for the visual part, they do not handle the logic for it fails. The solution is to overwrite the `stepBy()` method of the `QTimeEdit`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class TimeEdit(QtWidgets.QTimeEdit):
    def stepBy(self, steps):
        if self.currentSection() == QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit.MinuteSection:
            steps = 10
        super(TimeEdit, self).stepBy(steps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TimeEdit()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I have edited a new code, but it does not work I have 2 QTimeEdit the first must do the steps of the minutes, the secoda instead must be "normal".
Surely I'm wrong, but I do not know what.
Thanks for the attention.
Vittorio

Comment: @Vittorio You forgot to add: `super(TimeEdit, self).stepBy(steps)`

Comment: @Vittorio some feedback?